# How to include files depending on the request.domain

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, bootstrap-sass

I need to include the file

```
"#{request.domain.split(".").first}.css.scss"
```

into my custom.css.scss file.

I don't know how to proceed. The goal is to declare specific variable, and give them different values in each file, loading dynamically different files for each different request

file one.css.scss

```
  $button_primary_color: #xxx;
  $header_background_color: blue;
```

file two.css.scss

```
  $button_primary_color: #zzz;
  $header_background_color: red;
```

I also tried using CSS3 variables, without success:

```
home[sn="one"] {
  --button_primary_color: #xxx;
}
home[sn="two"] {
  --button_primary_color: #yyy;
}
```

(it doesn't behave standard in the different browser), and also it doesn't substitute the following statement.

```
div {
    color: var(--button_primary_color);
}
```

I'd like to have a more bootstrap/sass solution. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to figure out a best method, but one thing I've done in the past is to set the config.assets.precompile to effectively have domain specific css files and then have your layout generate the appropriate code to pull in that specific css file.

config.assets.precompile += %w( application.js application.css domain1.css domain2.css)

where you have in your asset pipeline 
domain1.css pulling in whatever domain specific code you need.

much cleaner than trying to include logic switches within the css code (which you cannot do btw afaik).